# How to construct tree pattern matching algorithm in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, parsing, tree, recursive-descent

Okay this is a bit of an involved question, but tl;dr it's basically *how do you parse an "actual tree" using a "pattern tree"?* How do you check if a particular tree instance is matched by a specific pattern tree?

To start, we have the structure of our *pattern tree*. The pattern tree can generally contain these types of nodes:

- `sequence` node: Matches a sequence of items (zero or more).
- `optional` node: Matches one or zero items.
- `class` node: Delegates to another pattern tree to match.
- `first` node: Matches the first child pattern it finds out of a set.
- `interlace` node: Matches any of the child patterns in any order.
- `text` node: Matches direct text.

That should be good enough for this question. There are a few more node types, but these are the main ones. Essentially it is like a regular expression or grammar tree.

We can start with a simple pattern tree:

```
<sequence>
  <text value="foo">
    <text value="bar" />
  </text>
</sequence>
```

This should match any of the following **trees** of text.

```
<foo><bar/></foo><foo><bar/></foo><foo><bar/></foo>
<foo><bar/></foo>
<foo><bar/></foo><foo><bar/></foo>
```

More specifically, you should imagine that as JSON and the pattern tree as JSON as well.

```
{
  "tag": "foo",
  "children": [
    { "tag": "bar" }
  ]
}
```

And the sequence pattern tree is like this:

```
{
  "type": "sequence",
  "children": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "value": "foo",
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "value": "bar"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

A more complex example would be like this for a pattern tree:

```
matchThing = <text name="thing">
  <text />
  <sequence>
    <first>
      <class name="value"/>
      <class name="function"/>
    </first>
  </sequence>
</text>

matchFunction = <text name="function">
  <text />
  <sequence>
    <text name="input">
      <text />
    </text>
  </sequence>
  <sequence>
    <text name="call">
      <text />
    </text>
  </sequence>
</text>

matchValue = <text name="value">
  <text />
</text>
```

It would match text like this:

```
<thing>
  <call-me-anything />
  <function>
    <input><foo/></input>
    <input><bar/></input>
    <call><foo/></call>
    <call><foo/></call>
    <call><bar/></call>
    <call><bar/></call>
  </function>
  <function>
    <call><baz/></call>
  </function>
  <value>
    <hello/>
  </value>
  <function>
    <input><hello/></input>
    <call><world/></input>
  </function>
</thing>
```

So imagine that as JSON as well.

Wondering how you go about creating an algorithm for this. I am stuck at the beginning, but it seems to require something like recursive descent of some sort, but on trees rather than on sequences.

So you have a function:

```
function checkIfMatch(actualTree, patternTree) {
  for (node in actualTree) {
    if (!checkIfMatchesSubtree(node, patternTree)) {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
}
```

I don't really know how to begin this one, and am searching Google for "[tree pattern matching algorithms](http://wwwmayr.informatik.tu-muenchen.de/konferenzen/Jass03/presentations/schwartz.pdf)" or "[arbology](http://arbology.fit.cvut.cz/)". Going to take a lot of time to try and translate those mathematical abstractions into code, if I am even going in the right direction. Wondering if you could help construct a simple algorithm for this case. It's hard to figure out how you should be traversing the actual tree, while also traversing the pattern tree, and keeping track of the position you are in each tree.

- https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/147190/Kybernetika_54-2018-2_1.pdf

Spending quite a bit of time on it doesn't get me very far:

```
function parse(patternTree, textTree) {
  let state = { ti: 0, pi: 0 }
  while (state.ti < textTree.length) {
    let pattern = patternTree[state.pi]
    let result = parsePattern(pattern, textTree[state.ti])
    if (!result) {
      return
    }
  }
}

function parsePattern(patternNode, textNode, state) {
  if (patternNode.type == 'sequence') {
    return parseSequencePattern(patternNode, textNode, state)
  }
}

function parseSequencePattern(patternNode, textNode, state) {
  while (true) {
    let i = 0
    while (i < patternNode.children.length) {
      let childPattern = patternNode.children[i++]
      let result = parsePattern(childPattern, textNode)
      if (!result) {
        return false
      }

    }
  }
}


while (stack.length) {
  let {
    parents,
    node,
  } = stack.shift()

  stack.push({
    parents: [node, ...parents]
  })
}
```

Comment: Seems hard. If you could convert your input into valid html5, then you could use css selectors.

Comment: Been some time since I had to deal with it, but I'm fairly sure that XML-schema supports pretty much everything you described. All you'd need would be a XML-to-JSON transpiler to support JSON and a XSD-validator for checking the pattern tree and you're good to go. Plus of course the code to compile whatever format your pattern-tree is defined in into an XML-schema. No need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: I want to learn how the algorithms are implemented, I used XML here as an example but my real project is using a custom data language, not XML.

Comment: Oh fun. Basically this is how object-scan works internally. Take a look at the code if you want inspiration. In particular the `find.js` file is of interest https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan/blob/master/src/core/find.js

Comment: @vincent interesting, it will take me some time to see how it exactly could be translated, but at first glance it appears not to support searching _by_ trees, only searching by lists (albeit with wildcards and other similar stuff).

Comment: I've spent a good deal of time on this issue, working on pattern matching in parse trees and tree refactoring. I learned that writing patterns using tree expressions such as XML or S-expressions is difficult. Instead of pattern matching with expressions that denote whole tree structures, it's much easier to reason and express paths through trees and the relationships between those sets. You should look at XPath. It is a well-defined language for this purpose. Alternatively, if you are just matching trees, you can just produce a sequence of DFS nodes between two nodes, and then compare that.

Comment: @LancePollard No, it works with trees for searches. In detail it works in two stages: the search is parsed into a search tree (https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan/blob/master/test/core/parser.spec.js) and that search tree is then used to traverse the input tree (that's the find.js)

Comment: Also, you should read papers on computing minimal edit distance in trees. Zhang Shasha is highly readable and understandable. And it'll give you a new way to look at these problems.

Comment: @LancePollard Actually, I linked the wrong file: This is where the compilation into a search tree aka "tower" happens: https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan/blob/master/test/core/compiler.spec.js

Comment: Just a hint: inspect a classic DFS algorithm to traverse the three, maybe You can get some ideas. After that, You can add a custom evaluator to each node. Here is an implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46389800/4845566

Comment: @LancePollard, do you only want to check the value part, or does the key part need to be checked too? is it ok to work with an object or do you need to parse the text as a tree of patterns and a test sample?

Comment: It's like validating a JSON tree against a JSON SCHEMA tree. You can look at this lib that does it in javascript https://github.com/korzio/djv/tree/master/lib/validators. There is a better one https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv but the sourcecode is in TS (very similar to js).

Comment: Could you please define more precisely what a "tree" is to you?

Comment: I don't get your patterns. Do "sequence" and "optional" apply to the children of a node? Is "first" basically an alternative? What does "class" mean - and can it recursively refer to the pattern itself? The "text" seems to match the label of a node - but why do your `text` patterns have children, what does that mean?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more the "interlace" one? Does it require at least one child pattern to match or can it be skipped completely (zero)? Can it match the same child pattern a second time?

Comment: @trincot the "interlace" one is for things like attributes on a javascript object: they are a set but the elements of the set can be in any order, but it can only match each child pattern at most once (or zero times). It can be skipped completely.

Comment: @Bergi "first" is like, say you have 10 children patterns, it will match the first one it finds (so it skips every child before and after). Sequence and optional apply to the children, the children are in a specific sequence, or optional. A pattern can recursively refer to itself (unless that proves to be impossible, I'm not totally sure on that one yet, haven't use it yet).

Comment: @Bergi The "text" one might be better called "label" or "basic", it is just the key/label, but they can be nested arbitrarily, and you can put sequences/optionals/etc. inside a label/text. Maybe it should just be called "node".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When attempting to match your pattern `p` to a tree `t`, you have to first match the root of `p` and its children to the root of `t` and `t`'s children. If `p` does not match at the root, then the children of `t` have to be traversed, and each of those child values matched against `p`.

Based on your posted input and node types, there are three main input scenarios that a recursive pattern matching function has to handle:

1. `p(object)` and `t(object)`. Here, the pattern is an object with type and child keys. The input tree is also an object with at minimum `tag` and `children` keys. The pattern matching function delegates to a helper function that carries out the match for `p`'s `object.type`.
2. `p(object)` and `t(Array)`. In this case, the tree is an `Array` of `object`s, and based on the pattern's object, the code has to decide how tree's `Array` should be treated (`sequence`, `first`, etc).
3. `p(Array)` and `t(Array)`. Here, both `p` and `t` are in the form of a sequence, and the match operation is to find, for every `a` in `p`'s `Array`, a corresponding `a1` in `t`'s  `Array` such that `pattern_match(a, a1)` produces `true`.

As a start, the code below implements a `find_match` function that supports the foundational nodes `text` and `sequence`:

```
//object that stores node match handlers
node_types = {'sequence':sequence_match, 'text':text_match}
//main find_match function
function find_match(pattern, tree_root, tree_children=null){
    var tree = tree_children === null? tree_root.children : tree_children;
    if (!Array.isArray(pattern)){ 
        //pattern is an object - delegate to handler for node type
        if (node_types[pattern.type](pattern, tree_root, tree)){
            return true
        }
        //no match at the root - check the children
        return tree.some(x => find_match(pattern, x, null));
    }
    //pattern is an array - delegate to sequence
    return sequence_match({'children':pattern}, tree_root, tree)
}
//text match handler
function text_match(pattern, tree_root, tree_children){
    if (!('value' in pattern) && !('name' in pattern)){
        //empty text node found
        return true
    }
    if (tree_root.tag === pattern['value' in pattern ? 'value' : 'name']){
        //match found at the root - continue match with pattern and tree children
        return find_match(pattern.children, null, tree_root.children)
    } 
    //no match - check the tree's children
    return (tree_children === null ? tree_root.children : tree_children).some(x => find_match(pattern, x))

}
//sequence match handler
function sequence_match(pattern, tree_root, tree_children){
    var tree = tree_children === null ? tree_root.children : tree_children;
    //copy the pattern and tree objects, as "p" is mutated as part of the match process
    var p = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(pattern))
    var t = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tree))
    while (p.children.length){
        if (!t.length){
            return false
        }
        var f = false;
        var f_seq = p.children.shift();
        for (var _n_t of t){
            //compare sub-pattern and sub-tree
            if (find_match(f_seq, _n_t, t)){
                f = true
                break;
            }
        }
        //no match found for sub-pattern in sequence, return false
        if (!f){
            return false
        }
    }
    //matches found for all sub-patterns in the sequence, return true
    return true
}
```

---

```
tree = [{'tag': 'foo', 'children': [{'tag': 'bar', 'children': []}]}, {'tag': 'foo', 'children': [{'tag': 'bar', 'children': []}]}, {'tag': 'foo', 'children': [{'tag': 'bar', 'children': []}]}]
pattern = {'type': 'text', 'name': 'thing', 'children': [{'type': 'text', 'children': []}, {'type': 'sequence', 'children': [{'type': 'first', 'children': [{'type': 'class', 'name': 'value', 'children': []}, {'type': 'class', 'name': 'function', 'children': []}]}]}]}
console.log(find_match(pattern, {'tag':null, 'children':tree}))
//prints "true"
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way - just to convert your 'pattern tree' to regexp, and then check text representation of your 'actual tree' with that regexp.

Regarding the Recursive descent. Recursive descent itself is enough to perform the grammar check, but not very effective, because sometimes you need to check pattern from beginning multiple times. To make single-pass grammar checker you need state machine as well, and that is what Regexp has under the hood.

So no need to reinvent the wheel, just specify your 'pattern' as regexp (either convert your representation of the pattern to regexp)

Your

```
<sequence>
  <text value="foo">
    <text value="bar" />
  </text>
</sequence>
```

Would be converted to

```
/<foo><bar\/><\/foo>/gm
```

And that perfectly matches this

```
<foo><bar/></foo><foo><bar/></foo><foo><bar/></foo>
<foo><bar/></foo>
<foo><bar/></foo><foo><bar/></foo>
```

I assume algorithm of the conversion pattern -> regexp is straightforward

Comment: How do you convert it to a state machine? Is there any resources on that? As I am using a custom language, we don't yet have regular expressions implemented, do I just lookup how to implement a regexp under the hood?

Comment: here is good comparison between gradient descent (aka backtracking) and state machine (finite automat) https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html. and description of idea how regexps based on state machine work

Comment: Do [regular expressions](https://deniskyashif.com/2019/02/17/implementing-a-regular-expression-engine/) support nesting of sequences though? I need nested sequences as well.

Comment: of course they do. (ab+c)+ will match things like abbbcabbbbbcabc