# How do you write an n-ary tree in postfix notation?

Tags: parsing, tree, notation

I am trying to understand [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1570866712001384), *Tree template matching in ranked ordered trees by pushdown automata*. The first step is having the tree in postfix notation.

How do I take a tree such as this:

```
foo
  bar
    abc
    def
  bar
    abc
    a
    b
    a
    b
    c
    d
    e
    def
    abc
  baz
    bar
      abc
      a
      b
      c
    abc
    def
```

And write that in postfix notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make a lot of sense. However, you can either use parentheses:

```
...(abc a b c)bar abc def)baz)foo
```

Or specify the number of operands with each operator:

```
... abc a b c bar4 abc def baz3 foo3
```

or even:

```
... abc0 a0 b0 c0 bar4 abc0 def0 baz3 foo3
```

Answer (score 1):

In the terms of that paper, the tree you are asking about is impossible because you have nodes with the same "symbol" (name) with different numbers of children. The paper, however, is assuming that every symbol in the alphabet has a specified "arity" (the number of children for a node labelled with that symbol). Leaf symbols have arity 0, by the way.

This is (very briefly) mentioned in the Basic Definitions section at the beginning:

> A ranked alphabet is a couple  = (*Σ*, *φ*), where *Σ* is an alphabet and *φ* is a mapping . The arity (rank) of a symbol *x* ∈ *Σ* is *φ*(*x*).

In other words, there is a mathematical function which tells you how many children a labelled node will have, which you can use in the postfix notation to know how many subtrees precede that symbol. (Note also that , which includes the arity function, is part of their definition of a PDA.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I would have not noticed that for quite some time.

Comment: Are there any "tree expression matching" papers which can work on a tree like I have described? (Not sure what to search for)? I am basically [trying to build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67441018/how-to-construct-tree-pattern-matching-algorithm-in-javascript) some sort of automaton for a tree, given a tree pattern.

Comment: @lance: you can use the paper you have but you need to add the arity to each node. A common way to write that is `foo/2` (as used in Prolog and Erlang). I'm really not a specialist on tree expression matching, though.